# IBM Watson conversation training status API

Tags: watson-conversation

I am using IBM Watson APIs to create intents and user examples and I want to know how to track the training status after creating a new intent and user examples.

Answer (score 3):

To track the status from within the UI, open the "Try it out" panel. It will display "Watson is training". When complete it will stop.

[image]

Programatically, you can use the Workspace API to query the workspace. For example in Python.

```
from watson_developer_cloud import ConversationV1

url = "https://gateway-fra.watsonplatform.net/conversation/api"
username = "USERNAME"
password = "PASSWORD"

workspace_id = '2d5e7dd4-19fe-4ab3-9c3e-f2eff48c9ca4'

conv = ConversationV1(
         username=username, 
         password=password, 
         version='2017-05-26', 
         url=url
       )

response = conv.get_workspace(workspace_id=workspace, export=False)

print('Status is: {}'.format(response['status']))
```