# Watson Conversation: What EXACTLY is Watson training when it is "training"?

Tags: dump, watson-conversation, watson

When the "try it out" box in the Watson Conversation Tool shows "training"

*(for instance: when it is getting the violet status "training" label text, when for instance assigning a new intent to a user input text)*:

What exactly is Watson training then? What is Watson doing at that very moment? Does this have an impact on the Workspace Data and JSON Dump Files created from this workspace?

I am asking because I am wondering the following:

- When I have a Workspace "A",
- I do a lot of training on it,
- I will dump this workspace to a JSON file and
- will use this JSON file to upload it into a new created Workspace "B":

Do I have to retrain workspace "B" AGAIN (because all the training data is lost), or will the such new created workspace "B" have all the "trained" knowlege from its original source "A" workspace? 
Is "training" something that will be reflected in the Workspace's dump JSON file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The training is creating a model that understands what each of your intents are. So that it can take a question it has never seen before, and able to map it to an intent (or know it's not related).

Each workspace is independent, so you need to create the model again if you move it to a different workspace. The training only regenerates after that if you change an intent or entity in the workspace.

You can use the workspace API to query the workspace, and it will tell you if the training is completed or not.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46785752/1167890

Comment: Is it correct to say, that the Watson Conversation AI-Learning part works on intents only but never on entities or defined dialogs? 
In this case of "yes": I am wondering why "Learning" is triggered by changed entities as well??

Comment: It trains on entities as well. They are to improve the intent model. If you make any modifications to intents or entities, the model updates. Dialog will not trigger training.